# Clickable edit summary options

Tags: feature-request

On the post editor screen, below the **Edit summary:** input box, change the current plaintext listing of options from

Briefly describe your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)

*to*

Briefly describe your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting, improved answer)

by turning the most common change reasons to links and when the user clicks on them, set (add?) it to the edit summary input box.

Comment: If you had it just fill out the field, you could append something specific before clicking "Save Your Edits".

Comment: Click and auto-focus on input box right after?

Comment: I'll do it myself somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this idea a lot. Mainly because I'm often lazy with the edit summaries, and clicking a button is easier than typing it out (after clicking around the answer...the edit box isn't vim, sadly).

Also, I'd like to append "made more awesome" and "made comprehensible" to your list.

Comment: I use "improved answer" for that. But yes, make it pluggable :)

Answer (score 0):

How about 'Edited Tags'.

Comment: You mean as 5th option?

Comment: If you only edit tags, the edit summary will say so if you don't fill it in.