# Edit Summary reminder

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary, reminder

#### Background

I usually want to include a short edit summary for all of my edits. But I must confess, that I'm sometimes a little lazy and forget to enter a summary. This wasn't a problem, when I had less than 2000 reputation, because I was not allowed to finish editing without entering a summary. But now, with more than 2000 reputation, I'd really like to have a similar edit summary reminder as an optional feature.

#### Feature Request

- Add an optional *Edit Summary* reminder for users with more than 2000 reputation. When one clicks on <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, this reminder should kick in and tell the user, that he has not yet entered a meaningful summary. Users should be able to ignore this reminder and possibly disable it completely.
- *Optional improvement*: Ideally this feature could be combined with a clickable list of predefined common edit summaries, as described in this feature request: [Clickable edit summary options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6683/clickable-edit-summary-options).

#### Possible Workaround

When one forgets to enter a summary, one can still change the default edit summary within the next 5 minutes by following this approach: [Editing edit summaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96918/editing-edit-summaries).

Comment: Irony: I forgot to add an edit summary in this very question after editing it. I wanted to add an edit summary but to add an edit summary I have to edit *something* again.

Comment: @hims056 you can just add a blank space, it won't count as new revision when done in the grace period. :)

Comment: I always include an edit summary now - mainly out of habit from my under-2k edits :)

Comment: And I always forget about it - mainly because I was reminded anyway before 2k reputation ;)

Comment: German Wikipedia tried this in 2007 (asking confirmation before saving an edit without edit summary) for unregistered users, and the result was a 25 % decrease in editing: https://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/PlotEditsSmallDE.png